# Can a dynamically allocated shared_ptr delete itself via the dtor of the object it's managing?

Tags: c++, multithreading

When answering another question, it occurred to me that I maybe optimize some of my own older code that has err.. 'less than optimal' lifetime management.

I have at least one app where access/lifetime an object is controlled with a shared_ptr. This ptr is dynamically allocated so that it can be 'atomically' swapped out for another *shared_ptr, (and hence an updated object managed by the new ptr), without any locking.  This seems to work fine, but I deliberately leak the old ptr because I don't know when the last thread is going to be finished with it.

It occured to me now that I could, (maybe), delete() the old *shared_ptr in the dtor of the old object being managed.  I would load the *sharedPtr into a private data member of the managed object upon creation so that the dtor could delete it.

Has anyone done this, or have any views on why it might be unsafe?  I could try it, but I'm worried that, like so many multithreaded 'optimizations' it might just 'appear to work' until after I delivered it :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have a bad design issue in your code more than anything else.  First off, why would you want to create a `shared_ptr*`?  That already seems wrong.

Then leaking it because you don't know when other threads will be finished with it? What?? That's bad.

Why not just have two `shared_ptr` and use them properly? Maybe that will make your life much easier.

Also, NO, you cannot get the `shared_ptr*` to delete itself with the destructor of the object it owns.  That would probably get into an unbreakable cycle.  Because the shared_ptr is trying to delete the object it owns, and then that will try to delete the owner, which in turn.... You get the idea... That is silly.

Comment: tend to agree with this... it seems like one too many object indirections.  sounds like maybe doing it so you can atomically swap objects between pointers... sounds like this is the fundamental decision to revisit.

Comment: It seemed like a good idea at the time <g>.  It allowed me to swap out the old global config for new global config without any locking. Maybe it's a bad idea and only seemed to work.  I think, on reflection, and reading your answer, and give that the old code 'works', I'll leave well alone and not try any changes that are unnecessary:)

Comment: OK, I have to accept somebody.  After rock/paper/scissors with Anne, you won!

Answer (score 3):

This is bad. It would be better to simply suck up the lock on changing the `shared_ptr`, or you could use DCAS to atomically swap a `shared_ptr`. Implementing that would be ... fun, but possible.

Your fundamental problem is

1. You need atomic pointer swapping
2. You need reference counting
3. `shared_ptr` does not provide #1.

So either suck it up and get out a lock, or you'll simply have to, say, modify `boost::shared_ptr`'s source code to permit #1.

I mean, the real question here is, why the hell did you make a global configuration? That seems like the real problem to me.

Comment: The global config parameters were used frequently by by many threads and were, like, 99.999..% read-only - only infrequent changes.  The more I think about it, and the more I read your answer and Tony's, the less I like my design and the more I think I have done a bad thing:(  I promise not to do it again <g>

Comment: If they're only changed infrequently, what's the problem with using a lock? You'd never notice the lower performance.

Comment: FWIW, C++11 provides `atomic_load`, `atomic_store` and `atomic_exchange` for `shared_ptr`. I have no idea who has implemented them so far and who hasn't, but if you were planning to modify the source code to provide it then it would probably be better to go looking/asking for the relevant patch first.

Comment: @DeadMG - it would require a lock on read, something that happens frequently from several threads.